# MapServer 7 arithmetic expressions do not work on STYLE attributes

Tags: postgis, mapserver, mapfile

I am trying to port my code from MapServer 5 (Oracle) to MapServer 7 (PostgreSQL),
but I am encountering a issue when trying to apply arithmetic expressions in the style class.
So previously in MapServer 5 I would have something like:

```
DATA "geom from (select pk, geom, size from sizes_of_thing) USING srid 3788 version 11g"
CLASS
    MAXSCALEDENOM 5001
    STYLE
        COLOR [size*2]
```

Which worked perfectly fine:
But if I convert it to MapServer 7 and PostgreSQL like:

```
DATA "geom from (select pk, geom, size from sizes_of_thing sot) USING unique pk USING srid=3788"
CLASS
    STYLE
        COLOR [size*2]
```

Throws an error such as:

```
msPostGISLayerWhichShapes(): Error (ERROR:  column "size*2" does not exist
```

By any chance are these expressions not supported anymore in MapServer 7/PostGIS or am I doing something wrong?

What I have tried so far is to write something like

```
SIZE [size]*2
SIZE ([size]*2)
```

create an expression like:

```
EXPRESSION ("size2" "[size]*2")
```

And use it in something like:

```
SIZE [size2]
```

create a validation variable such as:

```
VALIDATION
"size2" '[size]*2'
```

and then

```
SIZE [size2]
```

But seems like none of them work.

Answer (score 2):

It is documented https://www.mapserver.org/mapfile/style.html that mathematical expressions are not supported for angle:

> If you have an attribute that specifies angles in a clockwise
> direction (compass direction), you have to adjust the angle attribute
> values before they reach MapServer (360-ANGLE), as it is not possible
> to use a mathematical expression for ANGLE.

Maybe the same applies to other style items as well.

In that document page the only place where expression is mentioned is in `GEOMTRANSFORM [bbox|centroid|end|labelcenter|labelpnt|labelpoly|start|vertices|<expression>]`

Also in https://www.mapserver.org/mapfile/expressions.html

> As of version 6.0, expressions are used in four places:
>
> - In LAYER FILTER to specify the features of the dataset that are to be
>   included in the layer.
> - In CLASS EXPRESSION to specify to which features of the dataset the
>   CLASS applies to.
> - In CLASS TEXT to specify text for labeling features.
> - In STYLE GEOMTRANSFORM.

It seems that current MapServer version does not support your use case for expressions. You may write mail to mapserver-users mailing list and ask for confirmation.

Comment: I am afraid that may be the case. I just posted a question in the mailing list and will update the ticket with the result. But many thanks for the help!